# How do K'un Lun and Kamar Taj relate?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange-2016, iron-fist-2017

I'm not much of a follower of comics (perhaps I'm even not using the appropriate term for it), but I have seen the *Doctor Strange* film and some of *Iron Fist* - both creations of Marvel.

Now, in both story arcs, there's a hidden city, which looks generally middle-Asia-ish, and is hidden/difficult to access: Three permanent portals for Kamar-Taj, and a once-in-every-several-years portal for K'un-Lun. In both these cities, a monastic order trains people in martial arts and/or some kind of magic or magical knowledge.

How do these two relate? Are they supposedly in the same universe? Just a "aesthetic inconsistency" between the two stories? Something more complicated?

I'm asking about the comics and the movies/TV series (I realize there are different "versions" of the universe for both media).

Comment: Kamar taj and K'un L'un are astral plane neighbours

Comment: Damn, I really hoped this was about Homeworld: Cataclysm

Answer (score 1):

In the comics they are totally unrelated.

Kamar-Taj is "simply" a real world place located on the Himalayan mountains.

K'un-Lun instead is one of the Seven Capital Cities of Heaven, which are seven alien ships/alien worlds/realms in an alternate reality/cities hidden all around the world, depending on which source material you refer to.

Comment: But they have a very similar narrative function... you're saying that nothing and nobody has discussed their sort-of-redundancy?